# Measurable spaces and σ-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am stuck on the following problem and not sure how to proceed. Our textbook defines σ-algebra as a collection of subsets such that
(1) ∅ ∈ F (where ∅ denotes the empty set),
(2) if A ∈ F, then Ac ∈ F (where Ac denotes the complement of A in Ω),
and
(3) if A1, A2, . . . is a countable collection of sets in F, then
union of An ∈ F.

I cannot figure out how to show that the empty set is in F'. Is it because A ∈ F? Found some suggestions to show that A = A ∩ Ω ∈ F and F' but not completely sure how this helps. Below is the problem:

Let (Ω,F) be a measurable space and take any Ω′ ∈ F. Consider the set F′ := {A∩Ω′ : A ∈ F}. Show that this is a σ-algebra. Moreover, show that if F is generated by a collection of sets A, then F′ is generated by the collection A′ := {A ∩ Ω′ : A ∈ A}. (The σ-algebra F′ is called the restriction of F to Ω′.)

Comment: $F'$ is a $\sigma-$ algebra of subsets of $\Omega'$. It is not a $\sigma-$ algebra of subsets of $\Omega$. You should be clear about this distinction. $\emptyset \in F'$ because $\emptyset=\emptyset\cap \Omega'$.

Comment: I provided what the textbook has provided. It did not say whether F' is a σ-algebra of Ω'. Is that what the problem is asking us to prove?

Comment: Little carelessness on the part of the author. $F'$ is not  a $\sigma-$ algebra of subsets of $\Omega$ because $\Omega \notin F'$ unless $\Omega=\Omega'$.